# Android Canvas: Get Y position of drawn line in canvas

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quadratic Bezier Curve: Calculate Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634460/quadratic-bezier-curve-calculate-point)

I am doing some drawing on Canvas, I use Path.quadTo() with few points and my Paint has CornerPathEffect. So how can I get the y position of the line when x can be anything? Is there some algorithm behind CornerPathEffect which can lead to me get precise calculation in here?

Thanks.

[image: image of problem]

Comment: How do I know the t value for the formula here?paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(50)) does the proper transformation to the line.

Comment: t is the 'distance' between the two end points as t is between 0 and 1. So if you want the point in the center or half way it would be t=.5 percentage in a way.