# Getting the center point of a quadratic Bezier Line with SKPath (Skia Sharp)

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp, skia

I draw Bezier Lines with the `QuadTo`-Method on a `SKPath`. My requirement is to get a point on the rendered Bezier Line which is more or less in the middle of the line. I use this point to show a label on the line and to provide a hit point to interact with the line.
Currently, I shoehorned a simple algorithm which tries to resolve the points of the line vie `GetFillPath` and then try to detect the point which is nearest to the center of a thought straight line from the Bezier’s start and end.
This works, however, it feels extremely brutish. Is there a more sophisticated way to fulfill my requirement?

Comment: Does the case helpful  ： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596802/calculate-middle-point-of-bezier-curve ?

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic Bezier has a pretty simple parametric formula to calculate points lying on it, you can find it in many places, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

[image: Bezier formula]

As per description of your problem it is important to notice, that you don't specifally want to calculate the point B(0.5), as the length of curves (P<sub>0</sub>, B(0.5)) and (B(0.5), P<sub>2</sub>) can be different for non-symmetric Beziers.
What I would do is:

1. Flatten the curve to a polyline with an arbitrary precision p (selecting all the t params so that for every 3 consecutive t such that: t<sub>k</sub> < t<sub>k+1</sub> < t<sub>k+2</sub> distance between line (P<sub>k</sub>, P<sub>k+2</sub>) and point B(t<sub>k+1</sub>) < p)
2. Find k such that: L(P<sub>0</sub>, ..., B(t<sub>k</sub>)) <= L(P<sub>0</sub>,..., P<sub>2</sub>)/2 < L(B(t<sub>k+1</sub>), ..., P<sub>2</sub>), where L is the length of polyline.
3. Now with found k we know our middle point t<sub>mid</sub> fulfills t<sub>k</sub> <= t<sub>mid</sub> < t<sub>k+1</sub>. This can again be computed with an arbitrary precision.

For any higher degree Beziers you can use de Casteljau algorithm to calculate points for any given 0 <= t <= 1.