# Finding points on rectangle

Tags: math, graph, geometry, android-canvas

I am trying to find the coordinate of Z1 where the curve line intersect the rectangle. Given that I have the coordinate of center rectangle, center of the circle and circle circumference.

[image]

I have find this website but I don't have the angle 
[Finding points on a rectangle at a given angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061576/finding-points-on-a-rectangle-at-a-given-angle)

Comment: That depends entirely on what kind of "curve line" this is. It it some sort of Bezier spline? You will have to know more parameters then (and even if you know them, doing this analytically may be *really* hard...)

Comment: It is a Quadratic Bezier curve. That mean I also have the control point that I also know.

Comment: Set the equations of the lines equal to each other and see if they intersect within their bounds.

Comment: What do you mean? I just want to find point Z1

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the code on this site, for the intersection of a Q-bezier and a line segment: [calculating intersection point of quadratic bezier curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664298/calculating-intersection-point-of-quadratic-bezier-curve). Then just apply this check to all 4 sides of the rectangle.