# Intersection of Quadratic bezier path and line

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry, bezier

I am working with a svg element that contains a quadratic bezier curve in the form of a SVG path and a vertical line. How do I calculate the intersection between them programmatically?

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664883/11156131) and when I plug in the numbers from this question it returns the exact same value but not for the original numbers that I have in SVG.

```js
//referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664883/11156131
// linear interpolation utility
var lerp = function(a, b, x) { return (a + x * (b - a)); };

// qCurve & line defs - as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664883/11156131
//works for the following
/*var p1 = {x:125,y:200};
var p2 = {x:250,y:225};
var p3 = {x:275,y:100};
var a1 = {x:30,y:125};
var a2 = {x:300,y:175};*/

// current svg  points
//does not work for following
var p1 = { x: 200, y: 300 };
var p2 = { x: 640, y: 175 };
var p3 = { x: 1080, y: 300 };
var a1 = { x: 640, y: 50 };
var a2 = { x: 640, y: 550 };


// Calculate the intersections
var points = calcQLintersects(p1, p2, p3, a1, a2);

// Display the intersection points
var textPoints = 'Intersections: ';
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  var p = points[i];
  textPoints += ' [' + parseInt(p.x) + ',' + parseInt(p.y) + ']';
}
console.log(textPoints);
console.log(points);

function calcQLintersects(p1, p2, p3, a1, a2) {
  var intersections = [];

  // Inverse line normal
  var normal = {
    x: a1.y - a2.y,
    y: a2.x - a1.x,
  };

  // Q-coefficients
  var c2 = {
    x: p1.x + p2.x * -2 + p3.x,
    y: p1.y + p2.y * -2 + p3.y
  };

  var c1 = {
    x: p1.x * -2 + p2.x * 2,
    y: p1.y * -2 + p2.y * 2,
  };

  var c0 = {
    x: p1.x,
    y: p1.y
  };

  // Transform to line
  var coefficient = a1.x * a2.y - a2.x * a1.y;
  var a = normal.x * c2.x + normal.y * c2.y;
  var b = (normal.x * c1.x + normal.y * c1.y) / a;
  var c = (normal.x * c0.x + normal.y * c0.y + coefficient) / a;

  // Solve the roots
  var roots = [];
  d = b * b - 4 * c;
  if (d > 0) {
    var e = Math.sqrt(d);
    roots.push((-b + Math.sqrt(d)) / 2);
    roots.push((-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / 2);
  } else if (d == 0) {
    roots.push(-b / 2);
  }

  // Calculate the solution points
  for (var i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {
    var minX = Math.min(a1.x, a2.x);
    var minY = Math.min(a1.y, a2.y);
    var maxX = Math.max(a1.x, a2.x);
    var maxY = Math.max(a1.y, a2.y);
    var t = roots[i];
    if (t >= 0 && t <= 1) {
      // Possible point -- pending bounds check
      var point = {
        x: lerp(lerp(p1.x, p2.x, t), lerp(p2.x, p3.x, t), t),
        y: lerp(lerp(p1.y, p2.y, t), lerp(p2.y, p3.y, t), t)
      };
      var x = point.x;
      var y = point.y;
      // Bounds checks
      if (a1.x == a2.x && y >= minY && y <= maxY) {
        // Vertical line
        intersections.push(point);
      } else if (a1.y == a2.y && x >= minX && x <= maxX) {
        // Horizontal line
        intersections.push(point);
      } else if (x >= minX && y >= minY && x <= maxX && y <= maxY) {
        // Line passed bounds check
        intersections.push(point);
      }
    }
  }
  return intersections;
};
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 600" id="svg">
  <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="600" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
  <g id="controlPoint">
    <circle cx="640" cy="175" r="5" fill="green" fill-opacity=".5"></circle>    
  </g>
  <g id="qBez">
    <path d="M200,300Q640,175,1080,300" stroke="tomato" fill="none"></path>
  </g>
  <g id="limit">
    <circle id="upper" cx="640" cy="50" r="5" fill="red"></circle>
    <circle id="lower" cx="640" cy="550" r="5" fill="red"></circle>
    <text id="0" x="650" y="60">(640, 50)</text>
    <text id="1" x="650" y="560">(640, 550)</text>
  </g>
  <g id="vert">
    <line x1="640" y1="550" x2="640" y2="50" stroke="blue" stroke-dasharray="500,500"></line>
  </g>
</svg>
```

```js
//with the same numbers from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664883/11156131
// linear interpolation utility
var lerp = function(a, b, x) { return (a + x * (b - a)); };

// qCurve & line defs - as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664883/11156131
//works for the following
var p1 = {x:125,y:200};
var p2 = {x:250,y:225};
var p3 = {x:275,y:100};
var a1 = {x:30,y:125};
var a2 = {x:300,y:175};


// Calculate the intersections
var points = calcQLintersects(p1, p2, p3, a1, a2);

// Display the intersection points
var textPoints = 'Intersections: ';
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  var p = points[i];
  textPoints += ' [' + parseInt(p.x) + ',' + parseInt(p.y) + ']';
}
console.log(textPoints);
console.log(points);

function calcQLintersects(p1, p2, p3, a1, a2) {
  var intersections = [];

  // Inverse line normal
  var normal = {
    x: a1.y - a2.y,
    y: a2.x - a1.x,
  };

  // Q-coefficients
  var c2 = {
    x: p1.x + p2.x * -2 + p3.x,
    y: p1.y + p2.y * -2 + p3.y
  };

  var c1 = {
    x: p1.x * -2 + p2.x * 2,
    y: p1.y * -2 + p2.y * 2,
  };

  var c0 = {
    x: p1.x,
    y: p1.y
  };

  // Transform to line
  var coefficient = a1.x * a2.y - a2.x * a1.y;
  var a = normal.x * c2.x + normal.y * c2.y;
  var b = (normal.x * c1.x + normal.y * c1.y) / a;
  var c = (normal.x * c0.x + normal.y * c0.y + coefficient) / a;

  // Solve the roots
  var roots = [];
  d = b * b - 4 * c;
  if (d > 0) {
    var e = Math.sqrt(d);
    roots.push((-b + Math.sqrt(d)) / 2);
    roots.push((-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / 2);
  } else if (d == 0) {
    roots.push(-b / 2);
  }

  // Calculate the solution points
  for (var i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {
    var minX = Math.min(a1.x, a2.x);
    var minY = Math.min(a1.y, a2.y);
    var maxX = Math.max(a1.x, a2.x);
    var maxY = Math.max(a1.y, a2.y);
    var t = roots[i];
    if (t >= 0 && t <= 1) {
      // Possible point -- pending bounds check
      var point = {
        x: lerp(lerp(p1.x, p2.x, t), lerp(p2.x, p3.x, t), t),
        y: lerp(lerp(p1.y, p2.y, t), lerp(p2.y, p3.y, t), t)
      };
      var x = point.x;
      var y = point.y;
      // Bounds checks
      if (a1.x == a2.x && y >= minY && y <= maxY) {
        // Vertical line
        intersections.push(point);
      } else if (a1.y == a2.y && x >= minX && x <= maxX) {
        // Horizontal line
        intersections.push(point);
      } else if (x >= minX && y >= minY && x <= maxX && y <= maxY) {
        // Line passed bounds check
        intersections.push(point);
      }
    }
  }
  return intersections;
};
```

Comment: analytic solution have singularities (precision problems) why not search the BEZIER parameter and test if it lies (or its very near) to your line instead? seer [Is it possible to express "t" variable from Cubic Bezier Curve equation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113617/2521214) just use [perpendicular distance of point to line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776408/2521214) as error for the search. Note that search is slower that analytic solution for 2D and/or low degree of BEZIER but there are no singularities and if you set your search configuration and precision right its not that slow...

Comment: to avoid precision problems in analytic solutions you have to decide correct order of coordinates used while deriving the equations to avoid division by small numbers and or other mathematical precision problems ... which usually leads to have sets of equations (leading to the same result) and choosing between them based on your input values ... the decision will introduce brunches leading to slowdowns of computations which for more complex curves or higher dimensionality tends to be slower than search based solutions...

Comment: and also such robust analytic the implementation is usually way more code and also sequenced math operations leading to "slightly" lower precision due more rounding. while search is usually using simple equations (used "many" times in loop)

Comment: @Spektre no need for overcomplicated problem solving, it's just a two dimensional quadratic curve, so change the coordinate system such that the line is on the x-axis, and now you've turned the problem into a dead simple "find the roots of the parabola" with the quadratic formula we all know and love. If the required fidelity is "subpixel at best" because it's SVG on a webpage, then numerical precision is basically irrelevant =)

Comment: FYI, googling gives us e.g. https://blog.demofox.org/2016/03/05/matrix-form-of-bezier-curves/ which is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're basically doing is finding the roots of a parabola in a rotated/transformed coordinate system. E.g. these two images are the same pair of line and curve, but one is hard to work with, and the other super easy:

[image]     [image]

The reason the second is super easy is because we just need to solve the standard high school quadratic equation B<sub>y</sub>(t) = line<sub>y</sub> using [the quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

If we then also move the line down to y=0 (and the curve by the same amount) now we're literally just root finding, i.e solving B<sub>y</sub>(t) = 0.

We can do this, because Bezier curves are *invariant under transformation and rotation* so finding the `t` values for the roots in our rotates/translated setup is *the same* as finding the intersections in the original setup.

So... let's just do that:

```js
const { atan2, cos, sin, sqrt } = Math;

function getRoots(pts, [[x1,y1], [x2,y2]]) {
  // Transform and rotate our coordinates as per above,
  // noting that we only care about the y coordinate:
  const angle = atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1);
  const v = pts.map(([x,y]) => (x-x1) * sin(-angle) + (y-y1) * cos(-angle));  
  // And now we're essentially done, we can trivially find our roots: 
  return solveQuadratic(v[0], v[1], v[2])
  // ...as long as those roots are in the Bezier interval [0,1] of course.
  .filter(t => (0 <= t && t <=1));
}

function solveQuadratic(v1,v2,v3) {
  const a = v1 - 2*v2 + v3, b = 2 * (v2 - v1), c = v1;
  // quick check, is "a" zero? if so, the solution is linear. 
  if (a === 0) return (b === 0) ? [] : [-c/b];
  const u = -b/(2*a), v = b**2 - 4*a*c;
  if (v < 0) return []; // If there are no roots, there are no roots. Done.
  if (v === 0) return [u]; // If there's only one root, return that.
  // And if there are two roots we compute the "full" formula
  const w = sqrt(v)/(2*a);
  return [u + w, u - w];
}

// Let's test the coordinates from the question:
const [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]] = points = [
  [200,300],
  [640,175],
  [1080,300]
];

const line = [
  [650,60],
  [650,550]
];

const roots = getRoots(points, line);
console.log(`roots: ${roots.join(`, `)}`);

const coordForRoot = t => {
  const mt = 1-t;
  return [
    x1*mt**2 + 2*x2*t*mt + x3*t**2,
    y1*mt**2 + 2*y2*t*mt + y3*t**2,
  ];
};

const coordinates = roots.map(t => coordForRoot (t).map(v => v.toFixed(2)));
console.log(`coordinates: ${coordinates.join(`, `)}`);
```

As you can see, there is surprisingly little code required here, simply because we know we can turn a hard problem into a super easy problem with a change in perspective, and further simplify things by realizing we only care about the y coordinates in solving this problem.

Comment: Great answer! However, there is still a problem with the vertical lines as requested by the OP.  I may be missing a point, but whenever the line you are checking against is perfectly vertical - the intersection coordinates are not correct. There is probably a more elegant solution than adding a horizontal shift. See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/xxmVBxJ?editors=1010)

Comment: Pardon me, but my point is the current function just doesn't  return the expected intersection coordinates when the original line is vertical. Currently, the intersection coordinates equal the end coordinates of the quadratic bezier.

Comment: Looks fine to me? https://jsbin.com/nojiyofefa/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Many thanks for this great explanation and answer. I tried your code to my element and it is returning a weird intersection value which makes me feel that I am probably not doing it correctly; [here](https://codepen.io/smpao1/pen/gOZryPR?editors=1111). The intersection looks like ~(640,238 - derived through trial and error) whereas it returns (1080.00,300.00).

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, it's not so much the vertical line itself as it is "what happens when `a` is zero", because that'll give us a division by zero. I'll update the code to account for that when I'm back behind my computer.

Comment: Updated the code: when `a` is zero, the solution is linear, not quadratic, and the (single) root is at `-c/b`. I've also updated the example with the coordinates from your question, so when you run it, you get a single intersection at `(650, 237.53[...])` as expected.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is it possible to do this sort of calculation by directly using bezier.js for svg elements? I am a little hesitant cause I thought bezier.js is only made for canvas. I am not comfortable with canvas yet.

Comment: bezier.js is just for maths, it isn't tied to anything.

Comment: reacting to your illustrations (haven't read the code): the OP states the line is vertical, thus gives us x_0 to achieve; hence all we need is to find t such that x(t) = x_0. no rotations needed, just convert the curve to the matrix form to two quadratic functions, x(t) and y(t), for the given t interval (is it always 0..1 in Bezier?). x(t) = x_0 is the quadratic equation to solve. (are there any corner case?.. don't know). x(y) or y(x) being quadratic seems highly unlikely.

Comment: The illustrations are there to show off the equivalency, the runnable snippet uses the OP's actual coordinates, but the important thing is that the code in this answer is universal: it doesn't matter whether we have a vertical line, a horizontal line, or a line at any other angle, the code reduces every configuration to a root finding configuration.

Comment: you seem to suggest that y(x) is quadratic when you flip it so the line becomes horizontal. an I misunderstanding you here?

Comment: You are: _y(t)_ is quadratic, there is no y(x) when dealing with Bezier curves. The curve is a 2D parametric curve with separate Bernstein functions y(t) and x(t) with the control variable t in the interval [0,1]. By applying the RT described above the resulting configuration is one in which only the y(t) function is relevant.

Comment: yes, that's what I also wrote in my comment. OK. still, for the vertical line you need only solve x(t)=x_0, and there are no rotations.

Comment: Right, but that's if you only ever need a solution for vertical intersection, which is almost certainly not the case here (given the rest of the description), and definitely not the case for future visitors who have a similar problem and find this post in the future =)

Comment: flipping to horizontal and solving y(t) is not always going to work. imagine a line is given which is perpendicular to the one you show. then you must rotate the whole thing so that the line becomes vertical, and solve for x(t). y(x) or x(y) of course does exist, as an implicit function -- and we need to choose the orientation such that it is indeed a function i.e. one-to-one (as is the case in your right picture, but not in the left one). I wonder whether it is always possible, for *any* given line and curve.

Comment: That's one of the defining aspects of Bezier curves. [The component functions](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#components) are _always_ one to one with respect to the control variable.

Comment: re-read my comment. :)

Comment: I'd rather you come up with a concrete example where this solution _will_ go wrong, because until then I'm going to back this solution by simply saying that ["I might know some things here"](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo) and by using the realignment explained in the answer, we always have a valid root finding situation for quadratic, cubic, and quartic curves =)

Comment: Ah, I see it now. You're right. :)

Comment: With bezier.js `const intersectionPoints=[],controlPoints=[{x:200,y:300},{x:640,y:175},{x:1080,y:300}],bezierCurve=new Bezier(controlPoints),line={p1:{x:640,y:50},p2:{x:640,y:550}},intersections=bezierCurve.intersects(line);if(intersections.length>0){for(var e=0;e<intersections.length;e++){let n=intersections[e],t=bezierCurve.get(n);intersectionPoints.push(t)}console.log("Intersection Points:",intersectionPoints)}`

Answer (score 0):

The function works fine unless the line is vertical (`b` and `c` become infinity).

A simple workaround can be to give the line an invisible slant like so:

```
  if (a1.x === a2.x && a1.y !== a2.y) {
    a1.x += 1e-8;
  }
```

```js
var p1 = {
  x: 200,
  y: 300
};
var p2 = {
  x: 640,
  y: 175
};
var p3 = {
  x: 1080,
  y: 300
};

var a1 = {
  x: +vert.getAttribute('x1'),
  y: +vert.getAttribute('y1')
};
var a2 = {
  x: +vert.getAttribute('x2'),
  y: +vert.getAttribute('y2')
};

var a3 = {
  x: +hor.getAttribute('x1'),
  y: +hor.getAttribute('y1')
};
var a4 = {
  x: +hor.getAttribute('x2'),
  y: +hor.getAttribute('y2')
};


// Calculate the intersections
var points = calcQLintersects(p1, p2, p3, a1, a2);
var points2 = calcQLintersects(p1, p2, p3, a3, a4);

// Display the intersection points
renderIntersections(points, svg);
renderIntersections(points2, svg);



function calcQLintersects(p1, p2, p3, a1, a2) {
  var intersections = [];

  //add invisible slant to vertical lines
  if (a1.x === a2.x && a1.y !== a2.y) {
    a1.x += 1e-8;
  }

  // Inverse line normal
  var normal = {
    x: a1.y - a2.y,
    y: a2.x - a1.x
  };

  // Q-coefficients
  var c2 = {
    x: p1.x + p2.x * -2 + p3.x,
    y: p1.y + p2.y * -2 + p3.y
  };

  var c1 = {
    x: p1.x * -2 + p2.x * 2,
    y: p1.y * -2 + p2.y * 2
  };

  var c0 = {
    x: p1.x,
    y: p1.y
  };

  // Transform to line
  var coefficient = a1.x * a2.y - a2.x * a1.y;
  var a = normal.x * c2.x + normal.y * c2.y;
  var b = (normal.x * c1.x + normal.y * c1.y) / a;
  var c = (normal.x * c0.x + normal.y * c0.y + coefficient) / a;
  //console.log(normal, a, b, c)

  // Solve the roots
  var roots = [];
  d = b * b - 4 * c;
  if (d > 0) {
    var e = Math.sqrt(d);
    roots.push((-b + Math.sqrt(d)) / 2);
    roots.push((-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / 2);
  } else if (d == 0) {
    roots.push(-b / 2);
  }

  // Calculate the solution points
  for (var i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {
    var minX = Math.min(a1.x, a2.x);
    var minY = Math.min(a1.y, a2.y);
    var maxX = Math.max(a1.x, a2.x);
    var maxY = Math.max(a1.y, a2.y);
    var t = roots[i];

    if (t >= 0 && t <= 1) {
      // Possible point -- pending bounds check
      var point = {
        x: lerp(lerp(p1.x, p2.x, t), lerp(p2.x, p3.x, t), t),
        y: lerp(lerp(p1.y, p2.y, t), lerp(p2.y, p3.y, t), t)
      };
      var x = point.x;
      var y = point.y;

      // Bounds checks
      if (a1.y == a2.y && x >= minX && x <= maxX) {
        // Horizontal line
        intersections.push(point);
      } else if (x >= minX && y >= minY && x <= maxX && y <= maxY) {
        // Line passed bounds check
        intersections.push(point);
      }
    }
  }
  return intersections;
}


//referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664883/11156131
// linear interpolation utility
function lerp(a, b, x) {
  return a + x * (b - a);
};
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 600" id="svg">
  <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="600" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
    <path d="
             M 200 300
             Q 640 175 
             1080 300" stroke="tomato" fill="none"></path>

    <line id="vert" x1="640" y1="550" x2="640" y2="50" stroke="blue" />
    <line id="hor" x1="200" y1="280" x2="1200" y2="280" stroke="purple" />
</svg>

<script>
  function renderIntersections(points, target) {
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      var pt = points[i];
      let circle = document.createElementNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        "circle"
      );
      circle.setAttribute("cx", pt.x);
      circle.setAttribute("cy", pt.y);
      circle.setAttribute("r", "5");
      svg.append(circle);
    }
  }
</script>
```