# Apply backdrop filter to svg path element

Tags: html, css, svg, filter

I have a page with some background image.

In body tag I have a svg element with only one inner path element.

How to add backdrop-filter to path element so it could blur background in non-rectangular shape?

[image: svg path backdrop-filter scheme]

```js
$(function() {

  var pattern = "M0,{offsetTop} C{ax1},{power},{ax2},{power},{width},{offsetTop} L{width},{height},0,{height}Z";

  var $svg = $('svg#footer');
  var $path = $svg.find('path');

  var settings = {
    width: 1200,
    height: 200,
    offsetTop: 200,
    power: 200
  }

  settings.ax1 = settings.width / 3 * 1;
  settings.ax2 = settings.width / 3 * 2;

  function render() {
    var newPath = pattern;
    for (var i in settings) {
      newPath = newPath.split('{' + i + '}').join(settings[i]);
    }
    $path.attr('d', newPath);
  }

  TweenMax.set($svg, {
    force3D: true
  })

  var opened = false;

  function open() {
    if (opened) {
      return
    }
    opened = true;
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      overwrite: true,
      offsetTop: 80,
      ease: Strong.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
    TweenMax.to(settings, 1, {
      power: 80,
      ease: Elastic.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
  }

  function close() {
    if (!opened) {
      return
    }
    opened = false;
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      overwrite: true,
      offsetTop: 200,
      ease: Back.easeIn,
      onUpdate: render
    })
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      power: 200,
      delay: 0.15,
      ease: Back.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
  }

  $(window).on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    opened ? close() : open();
  })

  open();
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('http://i839.photobucket.com/albums/zz314/mrkanpuc/stuffs/1PZ1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

svg path {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<svg id="footer" viewBox="0 0 1200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path/></svg>
```

Comment: i believe this is not possible, a common trick to get something like this is to copy your background into a separate object, add a filter to that and add a clip path.

Comment: Maybe looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133329/how-to-use-css-backdrop-filter-on-text/63252650#63252650) (**the second solution**) may help someone with the same problem.<br>
Swapping the url path/mask with rect/custom one may do the trick !

Answer (score 8):

Without doing too many changes to your code, you can achieve that by increasing your `power` and/or decreasing your `offsetTop` in the open function.

```
TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {overwrite: true, offsetTop: 80, ease: Strong.easeOut, onUpdate: render })
TweenMax.to(settings, 1, {power: 120, ease: Elastic.easeOut, onUpdate: render })
```

```js
$(function() {

  var pattern = "M0,{offsetTop} C{ax1},{power},{ax2},{power},{width},{offsetTop} L{width},{height},0,{height}Z";

  var $svg = $('svg#footer');
  var $path = $svg.find('path');

  var settings = {
    width: 1200,
    height: 200,
    offsetTop: 200,
    power: 200
  }

  settings.ax1 = settings.width / 3 * 1;
  settings.ax2 = settings.width / 3 * 2;

  function render() {
    var newPath = pattern;
    for (var i in settings) {
      newPath = newPath.split('{' + i + '}').join(settings[i]);
    }
    $path.attr('d', newPath);
  }

  TweenMax.set($svg, {
    force3D: true
  })

  var opened = false;

  function open() {
    if (opened) {
      return
    }
    opened = true;
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      overwrite: true,
      offsetTop: 80,
      ease: Strong.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
    TweenMax.to(settings, 1, {
      power: 150,
      ease: Elastic.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
  }

  function close() {
    if (!opened) {
      return
    }
    opened = false;
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      overwrite: true,
      offsetTop: 200,
      ease: Back.easeIn,
      onUpdate: render
    })
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      power: 200,
      delay: 0.15,
      ease: Back.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
  }

  $(window).on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    opened ? close() : open();
  })

  open();
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('http://i839.photobucket.com/albums/zz314/mrkanpuc/stuffs/1PZ1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

svg path {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<svg id="footer" viewBox="0 0 1200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path/></svg>
```

---

### Quadratic Bézier curve

Another solution is to add a curved path (called [quadratic Bézier curve](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataQuadraticBezierCommands)) to your rectangle. The curve is built like this:

```
M{startWidth}, {startHeight} q {curvePeak}, {curveHeight}, {endWidth}, {endHeight}
```

- **startWidth** - x-axis positioning of `P0`: x coordinate where the curve starts
- **startHeight** - y-axis positioning of `P0`: y coordinate where the curve starts
- **curvePeak** - x-axis positioning of `P1`: where the curve reach it's peak
- **curveHeight** - y-axis positioning of `P1`: height of the curve
- **endWidth** - x-axis positioning of `P2`: dimension of the curve
- **endHeight** - y-axis positioning of `P2`: inclination of the curve

[image]

<sub>See also: [Quadratic Bézier Curve: Calculate Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634460/quadratic-bezier-curve-calculate-point) or click [here](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-curves/quadratic-curve.html) for an interactive example of the quadratic Bézier curve.</sub>

**Negative**

This solution has some problems when using two different [animations](https://greensock.com/customease) and duration, like in your case.

- [**`Strong.easeOut`**](https://greensock.com/asdocs/com/greensock/easing/Strong.html#easeInOut) : 0.35s
- [**`Elastic.easeOut`**](https://greensock.com/asdocs/com/greensock/easing/Elastic.html#easeOut) : 1.00s

```js
$(function() {

  var pattern = "M0,{offsetTop} C{ax1},{power},{ax2},{power},{width},{offsetTop} L{width},{height},0,{height}Z q 600, 100, 1200, 0";

  var $svg = $('svg#footer');
  var $path = $svg.find('path');

  var settings = {
    width: 1200,
    height: 200,
    offsetTop: 200,
    power: 200
  }

  settings.ax1 = settings.width / 3 * 1;
  settings.ax2 = settings.width / 3 * 2;

  function render() {
    var newPath = pattern;
    for (var i in settings) {
      newPath = newPath.split('{' + i + '}').join(settings[i]);
    }
    $path.attr('d', newPath);
  }

  TweenMax.set($svg, {
    force3D: true
  })

  var opened = false;

  function open() {
    if (opened) {
      return
    }
    opened = true;
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      overwrite: true,
      offsetTop: 80,
      ease: Strong.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
    TweenMax.to(settings, 1, {
      power: 80,
      ease: Elastic.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
  }

  function close() {
    if (!opened) {
      return
    }
    opened = false;
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      overwrite: true,
      offsetTop: 200,
      ease: Back.easeIn,
      onUpdate: render
    })
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      power: 200,
      delay: 0.15,
      ease: Back.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
  }

  $(window).on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    opened ? close() : open();
  })

  open();
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('http://i839.photobucket.com/albums/zz314/mrkanpuc/stuffs/1PZ1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

svg path {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<svg id="footer" viewBox="0 0 1200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path/></svg>
```

**Positive**

On the contrary it works great when using the same animation and duration.

Both with [**`Elastic.easeOut`**](https://greensock.com/asdocs/com/greensock/easing/Elastic.html#easeOut) : 1.00s

```js
$(function() {

  var pattern = "M0,{offsetTop} C{ax1},{power},{ax2},{power},{width},{offsetTop} L{width},{height},0,{height}Z q 600, 100, 1200, 0";

  var $svg = $('svg#footer');
  var $path = $svg.find('path');

  var settings = {
    width: 1200,
    height: 200,
    offsetTop: 200,
    power: 200
  }

  settings.ax1 = settings.width / 3 * 1;
  settings.ax2 = settings.width / 3 * 2;

  function render() {
    var newPath = pattern;
    for (var i in settings) {
      newPath = newPath.split('{' + i + '}').join(settings[i]);
    }
    $path.attr('d', newPath);
  }

  TweenMax.set($svg, {
    force3D: true
  })

  var opened = false;

  function open() {
    if (opened) {
      return
    }
    opened = true;
    TweenMax.to(settings, 1, {
      overwrite: true,
      offsetTop: 80,
      ease: Elastic.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
    TweenMax.to(settings, 1, {
      power: 80,
      ease: Elastic.easeOut,
      onUpdate: render
    })
  }

  function close() {
    if (!opened) {
      return
    }
    opened = false;
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      overwrite: true,
      offsetTop: 200,
      ease: Back.easeIn,
      onUpdate: render
    })
    TweenMax.to(settings, 0.35, {
      power: 200,
      ease: Back.easeIn,
      onUpdate: render
    })
  }

  $(window).on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    opened ? close() : open();
  })

  open();
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('http://i839.photobucket.com/albums/zz314/mrkanpuc/stuffs/1PZ1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

svg path {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<svg id="footer" viewBox="0 0 1200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path/></svg>
```

Comment: Can't speak for the OP, but I don't think this answers the question. The question is how to apply backdrop-filter to a non-rectangular shape. I personally tried many approaches (border radius, svg element, cutout) but in each approach, back-drop-filter is applied as a rectangular shape, not the non-rectangular shape you intend.

Comment: Your solution does not apply a back-drop filter. Check the screenshot of the question where the backdrop of the SVG shape is blurred. The OP's attempt does not do that, nor does your answer.

Comment: I have no problems with svg animations. But the question is how to apply backdrop-filter to a non-rectangular shape.

As i tested there is no chances to do that without canvas and lots of magic.