# How to calculate point on line drawn by quadraticBezierTo?

Tags: flutter, dart, math

I allowed myself to use image from other stackoverflow's question. I hope that's fine

[image: I allowed myself to use image from other stackoverflow's question. I hope that's fine]

So using using functions of `Path class` (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html) we can draw picture above

```
path.moveTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y)
path.quadraticBezierTo(handlePoint.x, handlePoint.y,  endPoint.x, endPoint.y)
```

My question is how I can calculate x,y of the highest point on drawn line ?

Comment: As for the image I think it is using  `cubicTo` to have two control point

Comment: [Convert quadratic bezier curve to parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1257576)  might help you.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Thanks. You maybe right about picture but I hope it just illustrate what I am looking for.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it seems complicated. I am looking for some shortcut. I think about getting inside the function and simply add some logic there. How can I override this ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know, but You can check [Quadratic Bézier Curve: Calculate Points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5634460/10157127)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Thanks. I think some of formulas out there will work. I just thought that there would be neat way of extending the logic of quadraticBezierTo function and actually it wouldnt be a shortcut.

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to add your answer after getting the one you were looking for. I've bookmarked it

Comment: check `PathMetric` class

Comment: You can include your answer on the answer section, and mark as answer

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I know I can

Answer (score 0):

Use any ui softwares like Photoshop. Create a canvas of same size that you are planning to use while drawing this path in flutter. Now use a pen tool and draw a curve. Now you should get a handle on each point. By handle i mean a line that denotes the direction and length of curve.  Check the right side handles position in the canvas using ruler (ctrl+ r)  that's the top most point you are looking for.. also there are a few online tools available to convert svg to path if you are looking for an easy alternative

Comment: I'm sorry if my question made you angry.

Comment: No no sorry if i sounded rude. Thats really a hack to find the  points. I have used this method to trace a design and find its points.

Comment: ok. I just didn't get the answer really. Would I get from there some formula ?

Comment: no you wont get a formula in photoshop. Sorry. May i please know what you are trying to achieve?  The formula can be found by clicking on the specific class you are already using.. hold ctrl and click on quadratic beizer to and it eill show all codes in that method

Comment: never mind, I won't be using photoshop for it. Thank you for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

ok So I went for PathMetric class, this is what is needed to find solution without finding the right mathematical formula.

```
List<PathMetric> metric = path.computeMetrics().toList();
PathMetric pathMetric = metric[0];
double lastPoint = size.height / 2;
double rightTangentOffset = 0;

for (double i = 0; i < pathMetric.length; i = i + 1) {
  if (pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(i).position.dy < lastPoint) { // only for up parabola
    lastPoint = pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(i).position.dy;
    rightTangentOffset = i;
  }
}
Offset position = pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(rightTangentOffset).position;
canvas.drawCircle(position, circleSize, circleOnLine);
```

you get an idea... lastPoint is due to where I start drawing.